# Angular : Several Component not recoginised by Module

Tags: angular, webstorm

Webstorm compiler msg
Error:(7, 2) ng: Component 'AppComponent' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule declaration

same for RegistrationFormComponent & AccountComponent

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
 import {UserService} from "./services/userService";
 import {CookieService} from "ngx-cookie-service/cookie- 
         service/cookie.service";
 import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
 import {BankService} from "./services/bankService";
 import {PaypalForm} from "./paypal-form/paypal.form";
 import {PaymentComponent} from "./transactions/payment.component";
 import {MicrosoftLogin} from "./services/microsoftLogin";
 import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
 import {LoginForm} from "./login/login.form";
 import {AccountComponent} from "./account/account.component";

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   AccountComponent,
   LoginForm,
   PaypalForm,
   PaymentComponent,
 ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
],
providers: [
  UserService,
  CookieService,
  BankService,
  MicrosoftLogin
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[project folder img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IScWi.png)

Tnx.

Comment: can you whole code of the app.module.ts

Comment: folder structure snippet also.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 2018.1.6 rolled back from 2018.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Angular language service issue, looks similar to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14961;

You can either disable the service in preferences ( **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript, Angular language service** checkbox), or restart it once the issue occurs: just press the **Restart service** button in **Typescript** tool window toolbar

Comment: it's a false warning, hope it'll be fixed soon.  Tnx for the enlightenment @lena